# NullPointerException при settext в JTextField

Tags: java

При попытке записать текст из файла `properties` в textField получаю исключение NullPointerException.
Выгрузка данных из `properties` проходит точно, значит ошибка с textFieldами. Но в чём именно, я не могу понять - почему-то они числятся неинициированными. Прошу помочь.
Код (лишние части вырезал)

```
public class Login extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
public static JTextField tfHost;
public static JTextField tfPort;

// свойства
public static Properties prop = new Properties();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                Login frame = new Login();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try
    {
        setConfigs(tfHost, tfPort);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {}

}

public Login() {
    setTitle("Авторизация");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, sizeX, sizeY+50);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    tfHost = new JTextField();
    tfHost.setBounds(10, 228, 228, 20);
    contentPane.add(tfHost);
    tfHost.setColumns(10);

    tfPort = new JTextField();
    tfPort.setBounds(248, 228, 114, 20);
    contentPane.add(tfPort);
    tfPort.setColumns(10);


public static void setConfigs(JTextField tfH, JTextField tfP) throws IOException
{
    InputStream input = null;
    try
    {
        input = new FileInputStream("clientCon.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        tfH.setText(prop.getProperty("host"));
        tfP.setText(prop.getProperty("port"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ошибка загрузки настроек:\n");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        input.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Так, внёс `setConfigs` в `try{}`, который внутри `run()`, и это помогло. Но я всё равно не понимаю, почему не сработало в этом варианте. Запуск `run()` происходит после полного прохода `main` что ли?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, JVM не ждёт пока main исполнится до конца. И в вашем случае тоже: новый поток будет запущен параллельно. Это напрямую зависит от способа запуска нового потока (в вашем случае, это поток Event Dispatch Thread).

Все дело в том, что если вызывать конструктор JFrame при помощи метода invokeLater(), то он поставит в очередь к  EDT вызов конструктора, который произойдёт в ближайшем будущем, но не моментально! В этом вся и беда, что ваш код в main напросто успевает обратиться к пустому указателю на объект типа JTextField до того, как был вызван конструктор JTextField.

Кстати, есть для Swing класс SwingUtilities, при помощи которого желательно запускать ваши приложения. В нем также есть  метод invokeLater() и вам просто остаётся импортировать этот класс и заменить EventQueue на SwingUtilites (источник: Иван Портянкин: Эффектные пользовательские интерфейсы)